# Groupby Categorical with percentages and totals?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Trying to group by a state with different countries and facing a problem where I have columns of percentage values such as unemployment, other columns with fixed values such as lat and lon, and other columns with numeric values such as totals so doing summation yields inaccurate results.

what approaches to such a problem can I implement?

dataset sample:

```
          county state  total_votes20  votes20_Donald_Trump  \
685         Dale    AL        19699.0               14281.0   
716       DeKalb    AL        29322.0               24744.0   
1546  Lauderdale    AL        44149.0               31578.0   

      votes20_Joe_Biden        lat       long   cases  deaths  TotalPop  ...  \
685              5154.0  31.430371 -85.610957  1926.0    52.0   49393.0  ...   
716              4271.0  34.459469 -85.807829  3691.0    30.0   71194.0  ...   
1546            11872.0  34.901719 -87.656247  2743.0    43.0   92590.0  ...   

      Walk  OtherTransp  WorkAtHome  MeanCommute  Employed  PrivateWork  \
685    2.1          1.8         2.2         20.7   17988.0         73.6   
716    0.9          0.6         2.1         23.2   28416.0         78.0   
1546   1.7          0.7         1.8         24.1   39857.0         77.6   

      PublicWork  SelfEmployed  FamilyWork  Unemployment  
685         20.7           5.6         0.2          10.4  
716         12.1           9.7         0.1           5.1  
1546        15.6           6.6         0.1           6.6
```

Comment: what is the actual problem you're facing?

Comment: Whats stopping you to limit only the required columns and aggregations associated to each on of them

Comment: I need all features to feed a ML modl and percentage columns can't be used as sum agg

Comment: maybe divide percentage columns by the count of each state ?